# Show only exposed filter when field data is available

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-exposed-filter

Suppose my website sells cars and other methods of transportation. I have a content type called Product and it is categorised with a taxonomy, eg. Cars, Bicyces, Boats, Helicopters.

The `Product` content-type has some CCK fields to describe basic features of the product, such as `horsepower`, `number_of_wheels`, and `top_speed`.

I use views to override the taxonomy term page, and show some exposed filters so the user can narrow their choices.

My problem is, that some of my exposed filters aren't really applicable when viewing certain terms. For example if I'm viewing the Bicycles term, I don't want to be able to filter by `horsepower`! Or if I'm viewing Boats I don't want to be able to filter by `number_of_wheels` (because none of my boats have wheels).

So is there a way to hide an exposed filter for a field if no rows in the view contain data in that field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having just one content type "Products" although simple, will ultimately cause redundancies and problems, such as what your experiencing now. It's far better to add individual content types; cars, bikes, boats and set fields unique to them. That way you can create filters easily in views against the content type.

If you were to create the table in mysql would you have just one table Products? I hope not. ;-)

Comment: Yeah I see exactly what you mean, thanks for your comments Gary. I was trying to leave it flexible to allow (using my example) a hybrid car-boat product to exist nicely. I think I will just have to suck it up and split into separate content types. Thanks again!

Comment: "Hybrid car-boat" sounds nice, I want one! Anyway, for this case I'd create a new content-type again to show "Amphibious car" -- what's nice in Drupal is you don't have to create the fields over and over, you can re-use them in new content types (simply select from the dropdown menu in CCK). You have Fields and Field Instances. So for example you can have a generic field name "title" and attach this to many kinds of content types. For your case, select fields from the "cars" content-type, so it makes it easier to create in CCK. Once it's made, you need not worry about it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not able to branch your content types as Gary Green suggests, making separate views (with more granular control of view filters), you could perhaps you could use hook_form_alter to check the default value of the taxonomy field corresponding to your product type (bicycles, boats, etc.), and then remove fields by setting #access for those fields to FALSE.

If you're not comfortable with using hook_form_alter, you could also set these to display: none with jQuery (don't remove them, or the forms won't pass the security / integrity test upon submission).  Unfortunately you can't do this with simple css because, at least in D6, CCK filter input elements don't have specific enough id's or classes to allow easy css manipulation.

This presupposes that you have separate views pages for each of the taxonomy-determined product types; your description sounds like this type of setup.

Comment: Thanks for your reply James, I appreciate your input. I've never played around with field #access, so you've encouraged me to look into it for future purposes. Ultimately for this issue I think the most effective option for me is to branch the content types and sacrifice a small amount of flexibility. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you, derpal.  I agree that for this purpose it sounds like branching content types makes more sense.  Note that there's a module  packaged with CCK that you can activate ("content copy" or a name like this) which will allow you to create one content type with all your various attributes, which you can "clone" into new content types - then removing the various fields you don't want.  This will save you time & prevent errors in consistency across your product content types.